# Cyborg RAT mouse with xserver

Tags: xorg, x11, mouse

I got a cyborg RAT3 mouse. This mouse got some problem to work on linux.
I'm under lubuntu 12.10. I have searched some solutions on google.

I have done this : I created /etc/X11/Xmodmap file, and I put this line on the file.

```
pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Its actually kind of working. I just have a problem. When I boot my computer, its not working, I have to reload XServer, and then, my mouse works really fine.

So I got two questions.

1- How can I do to avoid reload XServer on every boot ?

2- The shortcut Alt + Print Screen Sys + K does'nt work. How can I activate this shortcut ?

Thank you,